# Complex value error in Matlab curve fitting

Tags: matlab

I'm using Matlab Curve Fitting Tool in order to fit a set of data (with x ranging from 1 to 3 and y ranging from 1 to 0) with the following custom equation:

> y = a*((b-x)/b)^c

I get the following error and I can't figure why:

> Complex value computed by model function, fitting cannot continue.
>   Try using or tightening upper and lower bounds on coefficients.

I tried with tuning the bounds and starting values of coefficients but nothing. It looks like the problem is somehow given by the power ^c (without it, it works).

Any help would be much, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are getting negative values for

```
(b-x)/b
```

Set the bounds for b so that it cannot get smaller than x. (b has to be equal or larger than 3).

Comment: I see, thanks for replying! Only problem is that I know b to be something between 2.1 and 2.3...how can I fix it?

Comment: By the way, even though it would have been useless for its result, I've just tried what you suggest and the problem's still there!

Comment: Currently I don't see where the complex values should come from other than what I've explained above. Can you please verify the values of b and x again and make sure (b-x) never gets negative. Please update your question with additional information, such as the complete call you run in Matlab.